# Correlational meta-analysis and moderators

Tags: correlation, interaction, meta-analysis

I have 3 correlations between A and B through 3 different studies :

```
   data :

   study   n     r      
       1  54  0,16      
       2  38  0,60      
       3  33  0,59
```

But I would like to do a meta-analysis controlling for a 3rd factor C.

I did not a find a way to do it, is there any package available for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seem to be two questions that you are asking (one implicit question, and one explicit question):

1. Can you meta-analyze the association between variable A and B, while controlling for the influence of variable C (implicit)
2. What package (for `R`, I'm assuming) can you use to fit this meta-analytic model

**Question 1:**

Yes, you should be able to meta-analyze the association between variables A and B while controlling for C, *if a few conditions are met*.

We often think of correlations as the effect size of choice to meta-analyze the association between two variables, but all you need to conduct a meta-analysis are effect sizes, and their variances (or standard errors). Regression weights are effect sizes, and their standard errors are typically outputted in most statistical software, so you could meta-analyze the regression weights of A predicting B from models (based on your three studies) in which B is regressed on both A and C.***

The caveat is that you need to ensure these regression models are comparable--this is the primary reason why most regression parameters get excluded from meta-analyses, because different models control for different variables, or the variables are scaled differently. So as long as:

- You only meta-analyze regression weights from models with the same groups of predictors AND
- Each of those variables is scaled the same way from study-to-study (so that their unstandardized regression estimates "mean" the same thing)

Then you should be able to get a meta-analytic estimate of the association between A and B while controlling for C.

*** Alternatively, you could meta-analyze the regression weight of B prediction A, from a model in which A is regressed on both B and C.

**Question 2**

This question isn't really on point for CrossValidated (supposed to be more about conceptual understanding than programming) but all of the meta-analysis packages for `R` that I'm aware of (e.g., `metafor`, `metaSEM`) can readily synthesize this kind of data, as long as you supply the functions with effect size and precision (effect size variance or standard error) data.